# extracting the word next to a specific word in a text file using java

Tags: java, text, nlp

I want to read a text file and print the word previous to known word say xxx for instance in Java.
Ive written this code in java using Scanner class.
but this code prints only half of the word preceding to "xxx" some other words preceding "xxx" are missing.
I want to know whats the problem and can u troubleshoot this code.

Test file contains stuff like

```
Blah blah blah.. man xxx create blah blah .. wander xxx blah... then xxx ..
Need to print man,wander,then etc.,
```

---

```
public class Searchright {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = null;
        String str;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("doc.txt")));
            str=s.next();
         do{
            //while (s.hasNext()) {
                 str=s.next();
                if((s.hasNext(("xxx"))||s.hasNext(("X.X.X”))))
               {
                        //System.out.println(s.next()+" "+s.next() );
                        //System.out.println(s.next());     
                        System.out.println(str);
                        //s.next();
                    }

              s.next();
            //System.out.println(s.next());

            }while(s.hasNext());
        }

        finally{
            if (s != null) {
                //s.close();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Searchright {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner s = null;
    String str;

    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("doc.txt")));
     do{
        //while (s.hasNext()) {
             str=s.next();
            if((s.hasNext(("xxx"))||s.hasNext(("X.X.X”))))
           {
                    //System.out.println(s.next()+" "+s.next() );
                    //System.out.println(s.next());     
                    System.out.println(str);
                    //s.next();
                }

        //System.out.println(s.next());

        }while(s.hasNext());
    }

    finally{
        if (s != null) {
            //s.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

remove `s.next()` before `do loop` and before `while` block inside `do loop`.
It escape words two times in one loop.Thus causing missing word.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already prints  `man` and `wander` though `then` is missing. I've updated your code a bit to use try with resources instead of try-finally and assigned the next word to a own variable which is tested for the required string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("doc.txt"))))
    {
        String str=s.next();
        String next;

        do
        {
            next = s.next();
            if( next.equals("xxx") || next.equals("X.X.X") )
            {
                // Need to print man,wander,then etc.,   
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            str = next;
        }
        while(s.hasNext());
    }
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just a simple one: you call `Scanner.next` 2 times in the loop instead of 1 time: This should work:

```
public class Searchright {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = null;
        String str;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("doc.txt")));
            str=s.next();
         do{
            //while (s.hasNext()) {
                 str=s.next();
                if((s.hasNext(("xxx"))||s.hasNext(("X.X.X”))))
               {
                        //System.out.println(s.next()+" "+s.next() );
                        //System.out.println(s.next());     
                        System.out.println(str);
                        //s.next();
                    }

              //-> ADDED COMMENT HERE -------------------------- s.next();
            //System.out.println(s.next());

            }while(s.hasNext());
        }

        finally{
            if (s != null) {
                //s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that the code should be as similar as the one in the question. It really just adds the comment that starts with "//-> ADDED COMMENT HERE"